# Python Tkinter Child Window Issue

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

**Hello**,
I'm struggling using multiple tkinter windows in python. 
Basicly, I have two classes which are also related to two different windows.
The main class shows the main window (parentWindow) and the other class shows a secondWindow (childWindow).
The following code starts the MainWindow:

```
#START THE APPLICATION
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title ("GEMEINDESTECKBRIEF-Menü")
# My main Application
runGUI = MainWorkspaceConfig (root)
root.mainloop ()
```

So far there aren't any problems!

Now I'm trying to open a second Window calling a function in the Main Class (kind of onClickFunction to open the Window)

```
def opendirFactsheetHochwasserGebaeude (self) :
    #validates the workspace resp. database directory and
    #print self.checkFactsheet2.get()
    #print self.inputSpace1.get()

    try:
        if self.checkFactsheet2.get()==1 :

            if self.inputSpace1.get() or self.inputSpace2.get() != "":
                 #write workspace environment to __initFile__
                if self.inputSpace1.get() != "":
                    self.writeWorkspEnv(self.inputSpace1.get())
                    #Copy file in seperate thread
                    start_new_thread(self.copyDefaultFactoWorkspace,())
                if self.inputSpace2.get() != "":
                    self.writeWorkspEnv(self.inputSpace2.get())
                # !!!!!!! START SECOND WINDOW !!!!!
                facthwgeb = Tkinter.Tk()
                facthwgeb.title ("Factsheet Hochwasser-Gebäude")
                runGUI = Factsheet_hochwassergebaeude (facthwgeb)
                facthwgeb.mainloop ()
                #facthwgeb.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', runGUI.closeFactsheetHochwGeb)
            else:
            #self.inputSpace1.get() and self.inputSpace2.get () =="":
                tkMessageBox.showwarning ("Keine Arbeitsumgebung festgelegt", "Bitte entweder einen neuen Workspace anlegen oder eine bestehende Datenbank auswählen!")
                self.selectBox1.deselect()
```

Still everything works just fine!! The window opens as expected and also the GUI-widgets are displayed and useable.
After finishing the given tasks the Window has to be closed and **HERE ALL TROUBLE STARTS!!!**
To quit the Window I'm using a button with a command function which looks like this:

```
   def closeFactsheetHochwGeb (self):

    try:
        if self.inputSpace1.get() and self.inputSpace2.get() != "":

            with open('%s/__initFile__.txt'%os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'r') as file:
                    # read a list of lines into data
                    data = file.readlines()
                    data[13] = self.inputSpace1.get()+"\n"
                    data[14] = self.inputSpace2.get()+"\n"
                    # and write everything back
            with open('%s/__initFile__.txt'%os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'w') as file:
                    file.writelines( data )
                    file.close()
            # self.tkinterFrame.destroy()
            self.tkinterFrame.quit()
```

The **self.tkinterFrame.quit()** closes not just the secondWindow (childWindow) it also closes the MainWindow (parentWindow) too. The **self.tkinterFrame.destroy()** function clears all widget from the window but the window still is active and visible!!

So, any Ideas how to solve the problem?
Would be thankful for any solutions!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YEESSS**, Finally I found the solution to my issue!!!!

*First Step:* In the Main Class which starts the ChildWindow I changed the code in the   function `def opendirFactsheetHochwasserGebaeude (self) :` from `Tkinter.Tk()` to `Tkinter.Toplevel(parent)` => the parent references the root Window. After changing the Tkinter typ the `facthwgeb.mainloop()`was also cleared because it is provided by the MainWindow (Parent)

*Second Step:* In the Second Class which implements the ChildWindow the function `def closeFactsheetHochwGeb (self):`did privously owned the commands `self.tkinterFrame.destroy()`which cleared the widget of the frame but not the window itself and the `self.tkinterFrame.quit()`closes the MainWindow and the ChildWindow => so both commands are useless!!

*Final Step:* The final resolution is to change the `self.tkinterFrame.destroy ()`to **`self.tkinterFrame.master.destroy()`** !!

Sometimes complex things can be very simple!! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Don't make a second `Tk()` instance; you can/should have only one root.

Use a [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) widget for `facthwgeb` instead. Also, get rid of the `facthwgeb.mainloop()` call, as again, there should only be one call to this.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I have tried Toplevel already and it don't changes the behavior of the **self.tkinterFrame.quit()** function at all! Is it possible to just clear **facthwgeb.mainloop()**??

Comment: @freeski_52: Since your code doesn't explain where `self.tkinterFrame` comes from I can't be certain, but doesn't `destroy()` do what you want when you use a `Toplevel` widget?

Comment: `self.tkinterFrame` is the reference to the `Tkinter.Frame() Widget` and `destroy()`in my case just clears the widgets of a window but not the window itself

Comment: Then destroy the Toplevel instead of the Frame?

Comment: That is actual a good idea, but I've no idea how to do that! The button which closes the window is implementet in the second class and so also the onClick function of this button. The function to start the window is in the main Class so how can i check button clicked and then destroy frame in the main class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `self.Frame1.destroy()`
Or whatever your frame name maybe
Sometimes you could have this
`self.Frame1 = tk.Frame(top)`